# symfony 3 foreach a array with Classes

Tags: php, arrays, symfony

How should i get values from json data that i put in my classes (Match, Player) i tried to foreach that, but it is difficult if i had it in classes, and i dont know how to solve it. How can i recieve the data from that?

How does the array look like: [array image](https://prnt.sc/hdzsei)

What i am getting: [error image](https://prnt.sc/hdzrkf)

```
foreach ($data->participantIdentities as $player)
{
     //do something
}
```

Comment: The error message has explicitly stated that it's private so you cannot read it.

Comment: Don't use images to share text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Match entity has a property called participantIdentities and it is private property change it to protected or public.

Instead of

```
private $participantIdentities;
```

change to

```
protected $participantIdentities;
```

or

```
public participantIdentities;
```

Comment: And then im able to get value from that?